# Ossip Bernstein's Game

Tags: history

I just came to know about the story of the great chessmaster Ossip Bernstein about how he was offered to play a game of chess to save his life ([details here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ossip_Bernstein#Biography)).

My question is, is that game available anywhere? Can anybody share any links?

Comment: chess.com's article fails to go beyond "rumor has it". It's safe to assume the game was not recorded (if it was actually played at all). https://www.chess.com/article/view/ossip-bernstein

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the legend of Ossip Bernstein, who supposedly played chess to save his life?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/33307/what-is-the-legend-of-ossip-bernstein-who-supposedly-played-chess-to-save-his-l)

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson okay, I see... thanks!

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson I saw that question, but that's not the question I asked. My question was whether the game was available. Your first comment answers it.

Comment: The answer to the linked question (and the source it cites) indicate that the story's documentation never rises above the level of hearsay / secondhand reports.